# Name error in python with nested function

Tags: function, python-3.x, smtpclient

I m getting error in running nested function in my python interpreter

```
import MySQLdb
import serial
import time
import smtplib


ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1',9600)
db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","pass","db")

cursor=db.cursor()

while 1:
  print("Waiting ;;...")
  print("")
  print("collecting")
  print("")

  time.sleep(3)

  x=ser.readline()
  time.sleep(3)
  if x>700:
     send()
     print"send mail"

  print("inserting into Database")
  sql="INSERT INTO vidit2(temp)  VALUES(%s);" %(x)
  cursor.execute(sql)
  db.commit()
  time.sleep(3)



def send():

 content="send"

 mail=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)

 mail.ehlo()

 mail.starttls()

 mail.login("emailid","pass")

 mail.sendmail("sender","reciever",content)

 mail.close()
```

Error:
python temp.py 
Waiting ;;...

collecting

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 24, in 
    send()
NameError: name 'send' is not defined

Please help.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike, say, JavaScript which will ["hoist"](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting) function definitions during compilation so that they can be called before they are defined in your code (just learned about this the other day so forgive me if this is an oversimplification), in Python you need to define functions before you call them (interesting discussion [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-June/606196.html)). This means you need to do:

```
def send():
...
```

before:

```
send()
```